# Improving SQL query so that you could get information from other tables using current table fields

Tags: php, mysql

How can i improve this query so i could insert also data from 'refer' table 
using 'refer_id' that i'm getting from the `facts` table..

this is my query

```
REPLACE INTO `table_name`
        SELECT network_id, type_id, topic_id, COUNT(*), date_id FROM `facts` WHERE `action_id`='1000' AND `type_id` != 17 GROUP BY topic_id, date_id
```

And the facts i'm reciving is (For example)

Network ID | Type ID | Topic ID | Count | Date

```
 1     |   2     |   983    |  113  | 03/01/2012
 1     |   3     |   172    |  93   | 03/01/2012
```

I am trying also to get the refer name(`refer` table) by the refer id(`facts` table) from the `facts` table..
how can i do that?

Comment: I answered as best I could, but you may need to provide some additional detail as to what, exactly, you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `inner join` to get from one table to the other:

```
select
    *
from
    facts f
    inner join refer r on
        f.refer_id = r.refer_id
```

To insert data into a table from another table:

```
insert into refer (refer_id, refer_name)
select
    refer_id,
    name
from
    facts
```

Comment: what i'm trying to do is inserting data to new table from two tables.. first inserting data from `facts` and getting its refer_id by the refer_id i want with the same insert to insert the refer_name from `refer` table.. kinda hard to explain hope you understood